# MYSQL unhex() in sqlfiddle.com is not equivalent to PHP hex2bin(), both give different results

Tags: php, mysql, sqlfiddle

I'm trying to use PHP instead of MYSQL to add key values in database

```
select unhex(md5('google.com')) from x;
```

**Output**

```
HVkg9LRLJ6gCvXfE8FNvWg==
```

however using PHP

```
echo hex2bin((md5("google.com")));
```

**Output**

```
Y ��K'��w��SoZ
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong here, any help ?

**Edit1**
Joachim Isaksson

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're getting that value, however doing your select at a MySQL prompt gives the same value as in PHP;

```
mysql> select unhex(md5('google.com'));
+--------------------------+
| unhex(md5('google.com')) |
+--------------------------+
| Y �K'��w��SoZ         |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What you're displaying is the *base64 encoded value of the same thing*;

```
mysql> select to_base64(unhex(md5('google.com')));
+-------------------------------------+
| to_base64(unhex(md5('google.com'))) |
+-------------------------------------+
| HVkg9LRLJ6gCvXfE8FNvWg==            |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How your value gets base64 encoded I'm not sure, however it seems to have nothing to do with the MySQL query you're showing. It may be caused by how you're fetching the value in PHP.

Comment: @HassanAmir SQLFiddle base64-encodes binary values to be able to output them in usable form as text, however that does not mean that MySQL does if you query it directly. The output is strictly SQLfiddle specific.

Comment: @HassanAmir [This fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/51310) shows that effect, SQLfiddle shows the exact same value whether you base64 encode it or not.

Comment: im trying to insert the data in binary(16) mysql column, it does work if i did it from mysql command line using unhex, but not working from hex2bin using PHP

Comment: @HassanAmir Could you add the actual insert code? It's very hard to answer things that aren't part of the question :)

Comment: marked answer as correct, i will post the php code below once i prepare it.

Comment: @HassanAmir You may consider posting the insert problem as a separate question, that way it will get more attention from PHP people than adding it to a comment :)